# Is there a way to dynamically add a sheet where it will be at the end when the script runs in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a simple problem where I want to add a sheet at the end of the tabs when my script runs, but I can't find a way to do that.

I have tried using the insertSheet script, but from what I have read up on, that requires a number index as to where to place it (below it is 17). I am sure there is a way to place it at the end no matter how many tabs you have. Similar to the insertRowAfter function, I am sure there is something like ss2.insertSheetAfter(ss2.getLastSheet) but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Here is my basic code within my script. Thank you for any help!

```
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ss2.insertSheet(17);
```

Comment: Have you tried `ss2.insertSheet();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ss2.insertSheet(); // Inserts a sheet that by default becomes active
var totalSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNumSheets(); // Gets the total number of sheets
ss2.moveActiveSheet(totalSheets); // Moves the active sheet to the last position
```